# java TCP server accepting images as well as strings from android client

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

i want to  send string messages as well as images.i am designing android chatting application which user is allowed to share images and chat(string) as well
Java Server is at the backend which listens and broadcasts.
I am going through several articles but still confused.
1)how can i send data and while at receiveing server can know its string or image?
2)should i have separate sockets for listening and then broadcasting for images and strings respectively
3)can i have an object which can hold strings as well as images in byte array and passit on to java server?
Please help
also i am confused that should i use objectoutputstream/dataoutputstream to achieve it.

Comment: I finally managed to do this by sending every message as a java object and each object has a field which says whether its text or image or whatever. and i converted image as an array and send it as part of my message object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Keep Seperate Sockets that makes it simpler,or you need syncronisation

1)use objectoutputstream for image thats fastest method of image transfer

2)use dataoutputstream for string

Image Sending code

      File myFile = new File ("d:\\ab.jpg");
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
      System.out.println("Sending...");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      os.close();

Image receiving code

    int filesize=6022386; // filesize temporary hardcoded
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;

    File f=new File("d:\\ab.jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    // receive file
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [filesize];
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    current = bytesRead;
   do {
       bytesRead =
       is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
       if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
    } while(bytesRead > -1);
    count=current;
    Copy=mybytearray.clone();
    bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
    bos.flush();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    bos.close();
    fos.close();
    Status=true;
```

Comment: Hey.thanks for the snippet and suggestion but since mine is broadcast server, handling two sockets will it be easy?for example a client is just exchanging messages (string) and he doesnot have image socket open. suddenly if other guy wants to share image,he sends to server and server has to broadcast to all.in this case server will not know abt the previous guy who was exchanging only test messages

Comment: thats upon ur knowledge ,JSON ,KSOAP etc .

Answer (score 1):

You have discovered the entire reason for an application layer protocol.  Sockets themselves just provide ways to send bytes they don't say anything about what the bytes mean.  This is where an application layer protocol comes into play.

You could design a protocol that first sends a type byte (0 or 1) for image or data.  Then you might also want a integer (4 bytes) for length (length of data or image).  This would allow the receiving side to read those first and know how many bytes to receive and whether those bytes represented data or an image.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Java `Serializable` interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

In summary, a class that implements `Serializable` can be serialized with no additional work if all of its fields are also `Serializable`. So:

```
public class Message<Img_Type> implements Serializable {
    protected String mText = null;
    protected <Img_Type> mImage = null;    // Img_Type must implement Serializable

    // ... constructor(s), get/set methods        
}
```

You can then write and read these objects using `Socket`s, `ObjectInputStream`, and `ObjectOutputStream`. To read (one) `Message`:

```
    Socket socket;    // initialize your socket
    Message msg;
    try {
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
        Message msg = (Message) ois.readObject();
        ois.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // handle exception
    }
    // handle message
```

Writing a `Message` can be done in a similar manner using `ObjectOutputStream`. In this example, you can check the `Message` fields against `null` to see what it contains.

One thing to be conscious of is that the constructor for `ObjectInputStream` will not return until it reads the header of an `Object` from the input stream, e.g. a `Message` is ready to be received. Additionally, closing the object input stream on the server will throw an exception on the client if they have a corresponding output stream open, and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and explaination.I am aware of serializable classes but i am puzzled about  <img_type>. should i have another class of img_type? if yes what should i put.I am sorry as am notclear about this aspect.Thanks again for your time

Comment: I don't have much experience using images, so I put that in as a generic type. If you wanted, you could remove all <Img_Type> and make the field a type like Bitmap. Looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html it doesn't look like Bitmap implements serializable. Perhaps you could store the array returned by `getPixels()`?